# sub-tables and referencing data in other tables in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

So this is new territory for me in Ruby on Rails but I am a bit stuck.

I am trying to make a holiday tour booking system and so I have 3 tables - tours, hotels and transport.

A line in the tours table refers to a hotel and transport in the relevant tables, but I also need it to a check against a date in that table and pull information back.

Also, in the tours table I need it to have sub tours - e.g tour a runs on these dates so subtour a, subtour b etc. It then needs to reference the date of hotel on that table to pull through available rooms.

Is this possible? I can only see the links for direct association at the moment in (http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can reference the Hotel table.

If Tour has...

```
belongs_to :hotel
```

and subtour...

```
belongs_to :tour
```

you can do (in subtour)

```
delegate :hotel to :tour
```

Then `my_subtour.hotel` references the hotel object that tour belongs to.